# how to use Bootstrap Select picker if I use bootstrap css and js files instead of tabler css js files?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-selectpicker

When I implemented bootstrap select picker inside template which is used tabler cs and js files got below mentioned error

`Error: bootstrap-select.min.js:8 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Constructor')`

how to fix this?

**update**

Used below mentioned code instead of bootstrap select picker

```
<input class='form-control' list='datalistOptions' placeholder='Type to search...'/>
         <datalist id='datalistOptions'>
              <option value='Aruba'/>
              <option value='Afghanistan'/>
              <option value='Angola'/>
              <option value='Anguilla'/>
              <option value='Albania'/>
          </datalist>
```

How to hide 'manage personal info' in datalist option?

[image]

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Comment: @dave that is solved

Comment: The 'manage personal info' part is a feature of IE Edge that appears if you're logged in to your browser. Try opening your page in an incognito window, or a different browser.

Comment: @dave okay thank you!